# Function modifying list outside function

Tags: python

Why is func(list) not able to modify the 'orig' list that exists outside of the function but func1(list1) is able modify the 'orig1' list?

```
def func(list):
   list = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu','fri','sun']
   return list

orig = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu','sat','sun']
ret = func(orig)
print(orig, ret)
```

```
def func1(list1):
   list1[4]='fri'
   return list1

orig1 = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu','sat','sun']
ret1 = func1(orig1)
print(orig1, ret1)
```

[Results of code being executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg1Ct.png)

I was expecting the 'orig' list in the first block of code to be unchanged by the func(list) function. I was under the impression that functions can't modify variables that exist outside the function.

Comment: In `func` you immediately redefine `list` to be something else. Use `lst[:] = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu','fri','sun']`. Btw, don't use `list` as variable name, use `lst` instead.

Comment: Inside the first function, when you run this line of code `list = [...]`, that _rebinds_ the variable name `list` to a **brand new local variable** in the function, and the connection to the global variable is lost.

Comment: Aside from the fact you are ghosting built-ins, you also have a logic issue with this line `list1[4]='fri'`. It should be `list1.insert(4, 'fri')`

Comment: Thank you all that makes sense. I understand not to use list and use lst instead.

Comment: From mozway's response, why does using `lst[:]` instead of just `lst` connect `lst` to the global variable `orig`?